# Reg Exp accept all words, but ignore a word

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>
```

Above code accepts all words. I want to ignore a single word.

```
<xs:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>
```

For example: a valid string would be: `Hello How are you`.
An invalid string would be: `Hello how are you Ingnoreword`.

Answer (score -1):

This would help you your previous question was same see this: https://regex101.com/r/gfd0DK/2

```
^((?!Ingnoreword).)*$
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)